# Is there a way we can pass tenantId with header while producing the messages with node-rdkafka library?

Tags: javascript, node.js, apache-kafka, librdkafka

I am using **node-rdkafka** library for one of my application.
So I have one requirement to pass **tenantId** with **header** while producing messages.
I checked the documentation but not getting what I required or may be I am missing something.
So is there a way we can pass tenantid with headers while producing messages with node-rdkafka library?

Comment: Why can't you include that within the message key or value?

Comment: @cricket_007    yes, we can send headers data with messages, but headers add some specific purpose to request so want to send header data with headers only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Support for message headers was added in [node-rdkafka 2.7](https://github.com/Blizzard/node-rdkafka/releases/tag/v2.7.0).

For example:

```
var headers = [
  { header: "header value" }
]
producer.produce(topicName, partition, value, key, Date.now(), "", headers);
```

See https://github.com/Blizzard/node-rdkafka/blob/master/examples/producer.md

Comment: Great that's what I was looking for. Let me implement this then will accept your answer. Thanks